# GPO cannot be accessed/is disabled/or has no extensions

Tags: group-policy

GPO is not applying and in the logs it shows that it cannot be accessed. But it is accessible from \domain.com\sysvol\policies{1C95124D-D9BE-4C67-B9E4-36EDC98DE5BF}.

Delegation looks same as other gpo. Any suggestion on how to debug the issue?

```
GPSVC(3b4.d74) 05:42:13:923 EvalList: Object <cn={1C95124D-D9BE-4C67-B9E4-36EDC98DE5BF},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=abc,DC=abc> cannot be accessed/is disabled/or has no extensions
GPSVC(3b4.d74) 05:42:13:923 ProcessGPO(User):  ==============================
```

There's no google result for the exact same issue. I've even recreated the GPO but still I get the same error.

Comment: What is the User version of the GPO?

Comment: How do I find it?

Comment: Group Policy Management Console, select the policy, Details tab. User version, Computer version, GPO Status.

Comment: It shows "User Version: 1(AD), 1(SYVOL). Computer Version: 4(AD), 4 (SYSVOL). GPO Status: enabled".

Comment: What are the list of files/directories in \domain.com\sysvol\policies{1C95124D-D9BE-4C67-B9E4-36EDC98DE5BF} and sbudirectories?

Comment: There's Machine directory and few more directories under it. and There's User directory which is empty. Under machine: Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpI.inf

Comment: What settings are in this GPO?

Comment: Its wsus settings. Just that it adds WSUS address to a policy.

Comment: If it is a traditional administrative template policy, if there is not a .pol file, that would be the issue. The GptTmpl.inf file is for security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error can be ignored. The issue turned out that the child domain gpo reported not found. Deleting it and re-linking it resolved the issue.

Later gpupdate /force and gpresult showed that the GPO was applied successfully but gpsvc.log still had the same error.